# wix reusing ComponentGroup for different directories

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I am currently writing an installer with WIX.

I put every project into its own `ComponentGroup` like this:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="CG.MyLib" >
  <Component Id="C.MyLib" Guid="{349e5aa6-d935-48fe-9170-a36928c13545}" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <File Id="MyLib" Source="$(var.MyLib.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" />
  </Component>

  <!-- #region Referenced Projects -->
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="CG.A_COMPONENT_I_NEED_IN_MyLib" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="CG.AnotherDependendComponent" />
  <!-- #endregion Referenced Projects -->

  <!-- #region References -->
  <Component Id="MyLib_References" Guid="{0c77a027-2b1e-44fc-9c1d-fcda80acb740}" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <File Id="SomExtraDll_I_Need.dll" Source="$(var.MyLib.TargetDir)\SomExtraDll_I_Need.dll" />
  </Component>
  <!-- #endregion References -->

</ComponentGroup>
```

**But now I have to install the same component group - into multiple Directories.**

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of the Directory element within the ComponentGroup ELement.

Directory- Sets the default directory identifier for child Component elements.

[ComponentGroup](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/componentgroup.html)

I tried this in a sample project using the ComponentGroup and I was not able to deploy the same component in multiple locations. So I read through the windows installer documentation and here is what I came across:

1. Only a single instance of any component is installed on a user's computer.
2. Never create two components that install a resource under the same name and target location. If a resource must be duplicated in multiple components, change its name or target location in each component. This rule should be applied across applications, products, product versions, and companies.

To sum it up, its a windows installer limitation. If you want to install the same file in multiple locations, you have to define them as a separate components with different ID’s. A single component can only be installed to one location using an MSI. Another option is to make use of the [CopyFile Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html)

[Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/organizing-applications-into-components)

[Windows Installer Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/windows-installer-components)

Comment: Yeah but I want to use the same files in multiple directories.

Comment: You know - reuse the same `ComponentGroup` for different folders.

Comment: Create multiple componentgroups with different ID and then specify the new directory ID.

Comment: @Peter, Windows Installer's component rules prevent chaos and enables reliable systematic operations on the entire set of whatever happens to be currently installed from any installer at any time.